# Cloudant Search: Is it possible to weight documents?

Tags: search, cloudant

Some documents in my database are more important than others, so they should end up higher in the search results.

Is there some way I can reflect this in the indexing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `boost` field in the `options` parameter of the `index` function. See http://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#index-functions.